#VALUE instead of a date in Excel once the file is uploaded to Sharepoint
Using this formula
=DATEVALUE(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,256))
so the date is picked up from the tab name and not entered manually. Works fine while on desktop, but once uploaded to SharePoint, works for 1-2 seconds and then shows #VALUE.
Tried playing around with the date format and using =CELL("filename") with the same outcome. Does anyone know what the issue might be here?

Yep, that function doesn't work on web.

You could try something like this Re: Betreff: workbook and sheet name via formula - Page 2 - Microsoft Community Hub
